# flexible query based on two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering

I would like to create a somewhat dynamical query based on numpy array. Ideally, the indices of one array (`uu`) should be returned, given the conditions for each column in a second array (`cond`).

The sample below demonstrates what I have in mind, and it works using a loop. I am wondering if there is a more efficient method. Thanks for your help.

```py
import numpy as np
# create an array that has four columns, each contain a vector (here: identical vectors)
n = 101
u = np.linspace(0,100,n)
uu = np.ones((4, n)) * u
# ideally I would like the indices of uu 
#     (so I could access another array of the same shape as uu)
#     that meets the following conditions: 
#       the condition based on which values in uu should be selected
#          in the first column (index 0) all values <= 10. should be selected
#          in the second column (index 1) all values <= 20. should be selected
cond = np.array([10,20])


# this gives the correct indices, but in a series of 1D solutions
#     this would work as a work-around
for i in range(cond.size):
    ix = np.where(uu[i,:] <= cond[i])
    print(ix)


# this seems like a work-around using True/False
# but here I am not sure how to best convert this to indices
for i in range(cond.size):
    uu[i,:] = uu[i,:] <= cond[i]
print(uu)
```

Comment: `uu[i,:]` selects rows and not columns, right? Not sure if I got the question correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't cond have always as many columns as uu?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy allows to compare arrays directly:

```py
import numpy as np
# just making my own uu with random numbers
n = 101
uu = np.random.rand(n,4)

# then if you have an array or a list of values...
cond = [.2,.5,.7,.8]

# ... you can directly compare the array to it
comparison = uu <= cond

# comparison now has True/False values, and the shape of uu
# you can directly use comparison to get the desired values in uu 
uu[comparison] # gives the values of uu where comparison ir True

# but if you really need the indices you can do
np.where(comparison) 
#returns 2 arrays containing i-indices and j-indices where comparison is True
```